# Who's time slice is used when a packet is carried in linux network stack?

Tags: linux, system-calls

From the man page, when calling sendto() to send a packet in blocking mode, sendto() will return after the packet is copied from userspace to kernel space(send buffer of the socket). Then userspace app continue to run. Every thread has its own time slice, if userspace app continue to run, there must be another kernel thread help to carried the packet from send buffer of the socket to net adapter, right? But if there are many user apps sending packets, how many kthreads are used to carry pkt?It looks unreasonable to use kthread to carry pkt, but I can't understand the story after sendto() return, if not so.